# Are there any "nano" or "micro" fusion reactors that can produce really small electric energy currents around 5 volts?

Tags: electricity, fusion

If there was such a thing, I probably would've heard of, but when I try to research about that on google, I can only see the fusion reactors meant to generate energy on the scale of supplying cities, countries and so on.

I heard that being big is the most efficient approach for nuclear fusion, but even then, going really, really small, maybe it would require less energy to produce less energy, no?

Comment: Practical fusion requires the fuel to be held together for a certain amount of time, which depends on the experiment. In the case of magnetic fusion, that time is going to be... well on the order of tens of seconds anyway. The fuel is moving about randomly and will eventually hit the walls of the reactor, so that is a limiting factor. By making the reactor larger, the fuel stays in it longer. This is very useful. If you don't want to make power, small reactors work fine. Google "fusor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

As yet, there are no fusion reactors capable of generating power continually, at any scale. Research is being done to try to develop the technology, and recently there was a breakthrough in which more energy was released than put in *very briefly*, but it will be decades before they can build even the big reactors for cities, let alone small ones.

However, there is such a thing as a micro fusion reactor: the [Farnsworth–Hirsch fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor) is small enough to fit on a tabletop, can be built at home as a hobby project (it is popular for school science projects), and does produce nuclear fusion. However, the energy you have to put in to run the thing is considerably more than you get out.

It works by using two concentric spherical electrodes with a big voltage between them to accelerate charged atomic nuclei inwards to meet in the centre of the spheres. If the voltage is high enough, they slam together hard enough to fuse. There has been some small-scale research to try to scale it up to the point where it produces more power than it consumes, but so far without success.

--

There are small [nuclear batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_battery) using nuclear *fission* rather than fusion used in the space industry for powering satellites, long-term underwater sensors, and even implanted into people in heart pacemakers. In one of the most common types, a radioactive substance (Plutonium or Americium or something like that) generates heat, and the Peltier effect is used to turn it into electricity. These are small and could generate low voltages, and last for many years.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html) for fusion reactions, the products, and the energy they carry away, which at the moment the fusion reactors planned will turn into steam  and other heat exchanges,

[image]

The output of energy of a single reaction is of the order of MeV

One Mev is equal to $1.60218e^{-13}$ joule.

1 volt is 1 joule/coulomb

The number of fusion reactions for your wished numbers cannot be small.

The smallest [test fusion reactor](https://www.theverge.com/2022/12/15/23510819/nuclear-fusion-ignition-breakthrough-physicist-tammy-ma) has been recently in the news, and certainly is not a pencil one.

Answer (score -2):

Lockheed Martin was developed light fusion design....news hasn't spoken about it. Course it's Lockheed, they can't even design fighter jets that work well anymore..so I'm not holding my breath
[image]

Small fusion reactors don't get pres attention...but its what we'll need for sake of safety. Contrary to waste claims fusion does not produce solid radioactive wastes,, but does produce huge volumes of radioactivity....in neutrons and gamma emissions. A modest size fusion compact power plant say.....5-10 Megawatts, probably need meter of lead shielding.

Comment: no progress reported since 2014?? https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/oct/16/has-lockheed-martin-really-made-a-breakthrough-on-nuclear-fusion

Comment: The project was shut down some time ago, prior to COVID. It didn't work (which basically everyone told them from the start).